# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level PS C:\Users\Mcami\Desktop>

Tags: python, ejecutar

Por que al ejecutar me aparece este error, este seria lo que intento ejecutar

```
edad = (input("Ingrese su edad:"))

condicion = edad >= 18
if condicion:
    print("eres mayor de edad")
 else:
    print("no eres mayor de edad")
```

Comment: La sentencia `else` debe estar al mismo nivel de sangrado que el `if`, tiene un espacio de mas. Por cierto, `edad >= 18` no funcionara, `input` en Python 3 (a diferencia de lo que ocurría en Python 2, que espero que no estés usando...) retorna siempre una cadena (`str`) y la comparas con un entero (`int`). O conviertes la cadena en entero (`edad = int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))`) o comparas la salida de `input`con una cadena, aunque entonces usa orden lexicografico ("9" > "10") y no querrás eso....